# How is supposed to work the "channel" function from ImageMagick's convert -fx?

Tags: imagemagick

I'm experimenting with imagemagick effects filters.
However, I'm struggling to understand the `channel` function of `-fx`...

I was expecting it to select the argument corresponding to the current channel, and return it, for example, `convert img.png -fx channel(1,0,0,1) out.png` would return a red image of the same size of img.png. But whatever I put in channel args, I always get a greyish image.

What is `channel` supposed to do then ?

Comment: Channels are specified for a single input image as u.r, or u.g. or u.b, or if a second input image, then v.r, v.g, v.b from the second image, e.g. `magick alpha.png beta.png -channel red -fx "(u.g+v.g)/2" gamma.png` to replace the red channel of alpha.png with the average of the green channels from the images alpha.png and beta.png

Comment: I mean the `channel(r,g,b,a)` function from the documentation https://imagemagick.org/script/fx.php (beween ceil and clamp in the list)

Comment: I do not know what that means. I assumes it limited the number of u.x channels that could be used in a -fx command. I do not think there is anything such as channel(r,g,b,a) or any channel command per se.

Answer (score 0):

I think this shows pretty simply how it works. Bear in mind:

- I didn't specify the image size, so it defaults to 1x1, i.e. a single pixel
- I set the depth to 8 so the range is the more familiar 0..255, rather than depth 16 with a range 0..65535
- `fx` works on a real number in range 0..1, so `0.0` means 0 and `1.0` means 255, `0.5` means 128

So, without further ado:

```
# Make R=G=B=1.0, i.e. R=G=B=255 (white)
magick xc: -depth 8 -fx 'channel(1,1,1)' txt:
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,0,255,srgb
0,0: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  white

# Make R=1 and G=B=0, therefore R=255 (red)
magick xc: -depth 8 -fx 'channel(1)' txt:    
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,0,255,srgb
0,0: (255,0,0)  #FF0000  red

# Make R=1, G=0.5, B=1
magick xc: -depth 8 -fx 'channel(1,0.5,1)' txt:
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,0,255,srgb
0,0: (255,128,255)  #FF80FF  srgb(100%,50%,100%)

# Make R=0.5, i.e. 128 and G=B=0 because unspecified
magick xc: -depth 8 -fx 'channel(0.5)' txt:    
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,0,255,srgb
0,0: (128,0,0)  #800000  srgb(50%,0%,0%)
```

Of course you can make a larger, visible image if you want to:

```
# Make 80x80 image with all pixels R=255, G=0, B=255
magick -size 80x80 xc: -depth 8 -fx 'channel(1,0,1)' a.png
```

[image]

By the way, if you are on Windows, all the single quotes need to become double quotes.